# Calculate spherical surface area of IR emitter

Tags: led, infrared

I have an IR LED emitter.
It has a 20 deg. beam width.
The total power radiated is 70 mW.
I want to calculate the power density (mW/cm^2) at a range of 30 cm.
How do I calculate exactly, the area of a sphere that is intercepted by the IR 
beam at 30 cm?

I have done an approximate calculation by assuming that the radiation is a cone, 
and I have calculated the area of the base of that cone, but this is approximate and I would like to calculate the exact surface area of the sphere, intercepted by the beam.

I did find one post of a similar problem, but the person who kindly answered the post simply gave the resulting number and did not mention the formulas he used.

If I have posted in the wrong forum, would you kindly tell me which is correct forum?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask this. I'd ask on the Physics SE. (But make sure you delete this one if you do ask on there so that the question won't get flagged for cross duplication)

Comment: it is a mathematics question

Comment: why do you need to calculate the area of an intersection between a sphere and a cone?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the spherical angle in steradians?  Or the area of the chord of a 30cm diameter sphere that is illiminated by your LED at the center, or what?

Comment: @jsotola That's his conceptualization of getting the surface area for only part of a sphere (aka the area illuminated by a conical beam)

Comment: @DKNguyen, i understand what what you are saying .... i asked the OP to explain why the intersection needs to be spherical .... walls do not present an intersect between a cone and a sphere

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1DIMC_enGB828GB828&biw=1554&bih=920&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Id6eXdS6CNqE1fAPpdKVmAI&q=surface+area+of+a+partial+sphere&oq=surface+area+of+a+partial+sphere&gs_l=img.3..0i24.27061.32690..33250...0.0..0.42.383.10......0....1..gws-wiz-img.74UvahvAZ_4&ved=0ahUKEwiUz7SHlpHlAhVaQhUIHSVpBSMQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgrc=_

Comment: Thank you all. I want to calculate the power density. The radiation is moving outward & is spread over the surface of a sphere, not the chord. The chord is easy to calculate, as it is the base of a cone. The area of this cone-base is less than the area of the section of the sphere. So it is close, for small angles, but as the angle of the radiated beam increases it is quite in error. The REASON for making this calculation is to be able to know the power into a receiving optical sensor - that has a specific cross section inherent to that device. In the area of RF, this is a link-margin analysis

Comment: Thank you all again. I found the answer. I am not that familiar with solid geometry. What I was looking for is the area of a SPHERICAL CAP. The formula is pretty simple. A = 2 x Pi x R^2 x (1 - cos(a)). I will close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all again. I found the answer. I am not that familiar with solid geometry. What I was looking for is the area of a SPHERICAL CAP. The formula is pretty simple. A = 2 x Pi x R^2 x (1 - cos(a)). I will close this question.

Comment: Don't close the question. It is OK to self answer.